# Can ImageMagick be prevented from overwriting an existing image?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When [`convert`](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)ing an image, ImageMagick's default behavior seems to be to overwrite any existing file. Is it possible to prevent this? I'm looking for something similar to Wget's `--no-clobber` [download option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options). I've gone through [ImageMagick's list of command-line options](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php), and the closest option I could find was [`-update`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#update), but this can only detect if an *input* file is changed.

Here's an example of what I'd like to accomplish: On the first run, `convert input.jpg output.png` produces an `output.png` that does **not** already exist, and then on the second run, `convert input.jpg output.png` detects that `output.png` **already exists** and does not overwrite it.

Comment: It's like most programs from the Unix world - it kind of assumes you know what you are doing. It's more like a Windows approach to ask if you really meant what you typed. I guess it's just a different ethos.

Comment: You can script a test if the file exists or not and then do your convert as desired. That is easy in Unix bash for example. See https://www.shellhacks.com/bash-test-if-file-exists/

Answer (score 2):

Just test if it exists first, assuming `bash`:

```
[ ! -f output.png ] && convert input.png output.png
```

Or slightly less intuitively, but shorter:

```
[ -f output.png ] || convert input.png output.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this solve your problem?

It will write to `output.png` but if the file already exists a new file will be created with a random 5 character suffix (eg. `output-CKYnY.png` then `output-hSYZC.png`, etc.).

```
convert input.jpg -resize 50% $(if test -f output.png; then echo "output-$(head -c5 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' | head -c5).png"; else echo "output.png"; fi)
```

Comment: To generate a random name you could use `mktemp output-XXXXX.png` instead of `/dev/urandom`. This is easier and also checks that the random name is unused.